# How does the AC bonus from things like Ring or Cloak of Protection work with Touch AC?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, armor-class

How does the AC bonus from things like Ring or Cloak of Protection work with Touch AC?

I know that when something targets Touch AC you don't add the AC bonus from Armor or Natural Armor but retain your Dex mod and dodge. Is the AC bonus from Ring of Protection also lost for Touch AC?

I'm asking cause when I look at the Character Sheet I am confused where to put the AC bonus from Ring of Protection. Do I put the AC bonus from Ring of Protection and add it to the armor bonus in AC box or what?

Comment: Can a link be provided to the *cloak of protection*?

Comment: My mistake I meant Cloak of Resistance but that doesn't give an AC bonus. But you can easily make it via Magic Item creation rules. Just use the spells used on on a Ring of Protection and apply it to a cloak.

Answer (score 7):

[Ring of Protection](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-protection/):

> This ring offers continual magical protection in the form of a *deflection bonus* of +1 to +5 to AC.

[Deflection bonus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Deflection-Bonus):

> A deflection bonus affects armor class and is granted by a spell or magic effect that makes attacks veer off harmlessly. Deflection bonuses stack with all other bonuses to AC except other deflection bonuses. *A deflection bonus applies against touch attacks.*

"Cloak of Protection" doesn't exist as a stock magic item, so only whoever made it up can say.

Comment: My mistake I meant Cloak of Resistance but that doesn't give an AC bonus, but the Snake Skin Tunic (http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/tunic-snakeskin/) does, it that item's AC bonus also count as a Deflection bonus as well lie the Ring of Protection?

Comment: What does the item writeup say? Does it say deflection bonus or some other kind of bonus?  Is that bonus then listed as working against touch AC (hint: click on the link where it says the type of bonus)?  Very basic research should be providing these answers for you.